# How to set 3 pictures on the same line

Tags: latex

I'm writing my thesis report and I get some help about LaTeX.
I would like to set 3 pictures on the same line and make 3 x 3 pictures per page.

This is my script :

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./Stage/Data/Field5_SN_map_final.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./Stage/Data/Field6_SN_map_final.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./Stage/Data/Field7_SN_map_final.png}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

But I get some errors :

[image]

Do you have any idea to solve my problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: Not a real answer, thus for starters a comment: subfigure became obsolete long ago, thus if you are able to use subfig instead, you might have support of a broader user base to help you. Secondly isn't subfigure expecting two parameters in curly braces instead of only one?

Comment: ... or maybe move this question to the [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com) :-?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should define figures' width in this way: `\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{your_figure}` and removing width from `\subfigure`. So the code should be like this:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{./Stage/Data/Field5_SN_map_final.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{./Stage/Data/Field6_SN_map_final.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{./Stage/Data/Field7_SN_map_final.png}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```